# Cannot send emails via gmx.net using Alpine

Tags: alpine-mail

When I try to send emails via gmx, I get: `Mail not sent: Bad sequence of commands`.
Sadly the error message does not help.
My config is: `smtp-server=mail.gmx.net:587/tls/user=username@gmx.net`

Answer (score 0):

Had to set

```
customized-hdrs=From: User Name <username@gmx.net>
```

in `$HOME/.pinerc` to make it work.